# How do I check which controller is used to render a partial in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple partial for my footer that looks like this:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "Download History", report_histories_path(format: "csv") %>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

The first link allows the user to download some data used to power reports as a CSV, but I only want this to link to appear if the `reports_controller` is used to render the partial.

I've tried using

```
<% if params[:reports] %>
  <li><%= link_to "Download History", report_histories_path(format: "csv") %>
<% end %>
```

as well as

```
<% if current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'reports')) %>
  <li><%= link_to "Download History", report_histories_path(format: "csv") %>
<% end %>
```

but neither show the link.

Comment: For which `action` of `reports_controller` you need to show that link?

Comment: All of them, ideally. @Eugzol answered my question, I'm just waiting to be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `params[:controller]` for that. Also, `params[:action]` will contain current action.

Comment: `controller.controller_name` and `controller.action_name` are cleaner than looking at params, IMO

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `controller_name` or `action_name`. Or specifically, to answer your question `<% if controller_name == 'reports' %>`

Comment: So my condition would look like `if controller_name == 'reports'`?